# Is it possible to atomically load and store on X86 processors?

Tags: c++, concurrency, x86, atomic, processor

Can this be done atomically?

```
void load_and_store(int* dst, int* src) {
  int data = *src;
  *dst = data;
}
```

If atomic store has to be done with `XCHG [addr], EAX`, I would have to load the data into `EAX` first. Then load and store are not atomic.

gcc atomic extension has `void __atomic_store (type *ptr, type *val, int memmodel)` which looks like being able to do both load and store atomically.

Comment: Is this different from `*dst = *src;`?

Comment: *dst = *src is not atomic.

Comment: @MarkB maybe my question was a little confusing. I was wondering if there was a CPU instruction which does the same thing as the function in C++ in an atomic way.

Comment: Looked at CompareAndSwap() ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not believe there is any instruction on x86 that atomically does both a load and a store, to different addresses.  (I'm not sure about other architectures, but I doubt there are very many, if any, that do.  It serves no useful value and would be expensive.)

x86 (and x86_64) have a number of instructions that can be made to do atomic read-modify-write operations *but only to a single memory location*.  For example `BTS` does test-and-set.  `XCHG` exchanges the value in a register with the value in a memory location.  `XADD` does an atomic increment.  `CMPXCHG` does a compare-and-swap.  None of these are atomic by default, but can be made atomic by adding the `LOCK` prefix to the assembly instruction.

The gnu `__atomic_store(type *ptr, type *val, int memmodel)` does not do what you think it does.  See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html.  What it does is load `val` into a register (or something (it's actually not defined what it does with val)) and then atomically stores the value into the memory location given by `ptr`.

On x86 *aligned* loads and stores (for values 32-bits and less) are atomic by default.

But you shouldn't be using the gnu builtins unless you have to.  Instead use the `--std=c++11` flag, and then use [the C++ `atomics`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic).

Comment: How large can "a single memory location" be on x86-64? Is it up to 64 bits or 32 bits?

Comment: In x86-64, _aligned_ 8bit, 16bit, 32bit, _and_ 64bit loads and stores are atomic.

Comment: unaligned 16bit, 32bit and 64bit loads and stores are probably not atomic

Comment: There's also a cmpxchg16b instruction that works with 128 aligned bits.  I don't know of any other instructions that work atomically on widths wider than 64 bits.